# I want to read and modify a .xlsm file in java and I am using Apache POI for it. while writing into .xlsm file my code is creating 0 kb file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read and modify a .xlsm file in java and I am using Apache POI for it. While writing into .xlsm file my code is creating 0 kb file. Same code works fine with xls format but in case of .xlsm format it creates 0 kb file. Can anyone please help me with it.

```
try {

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Scoring_03101995.xlsm"));
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);


        Cell celltUpdate = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(2);  //Scoring_03101995 file contains 5 sheets and each sheet has more than 20 rows and 100 cells
        celltUpdate.setCellValue(123);
        inputStream.close();

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Scoring_03101995.xlsm");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        //((FileInputStream) workbook).close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I did not have Microsoft excel due to which code was not able to create .xlsm file. After installation of Microsoft office error is resolved.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am facing with same issue.

Comment: Are you trying to write in an .xlsm file if yes then you must have Microsoft Excel other freeware doesn't support it properly.

Comment: Yes, I try to do it. I have MS Excel installed on machine. Should I use it somehow with Apache POI?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to write into file?

Comment: I think you violate the worksheet usage pattern: you try to write to output while input has already been closed.
Compare your code with the [sample from the documentation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook).
I have got impossible exception myself while trying to write to output .xlsm (even with different name) while input .xlsm has been closed.